# Tikz/PGFPlots produce different graphs when compiled on my desktop and ShareLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, sharelatex

I am experiencing a weird Tikz/PGFPlots issue.  For some reason, the y-coordinate of nodes is being places relative to the bottom of the tikzpicture instead of the origin.  The weird part is that it is *only happening on my computer*.  When I compile my minimum working example below on ShareLaTeX, the graph is perfect.

I cannot imagine what would cause this aside from some difference between the distributions, but I would very much like to learn if anyone has some insight into this bizarre issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={
        grid=both,
        axis lines=center,
        axis equal image,
        very thick,
        disabledatascaling,
        inner axis line style={<->},
        xlabel={$x$}, xlabel style={below right},
        ylabel={$y$}, ylabel style={above left},
        inner axis line style={<->},
        mark size=3}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,name=#1},
    extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
    extended line/.default=1cm]
    \begin{axis}[
    my style,
    xmin=      -12, 
    xmax=      12, 
    ymin=      -12,
    ymax=      12,
    thick,
    minor x tick num=4,
    minor y tick num=4
    ]
        \node [dot=A] at (-2,0) {};

        \node [dot=B] at (0,10) {};

    \draw [extended line=3in] (A) -- (B);
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result on my computer:

[image]

The result when I compile using ShareLaTeX

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps this is due to different _pgfplots_ versions? As you don't set any `compat=<version>` option, it will run in backwards compatibility mode. Do you get any warning regarding this?

Comment: I compiled the document and I get the same output than with ShareLaTeX. But this is not a minimal working example at all. What happens if you compile a simplistic document, with say only one word?

Comment: @anderstood I would call that a MWE. This appears to be a problem specifically about `pgfplots`, what's the benefit of not including `pgfplots` in the example?

Comment: @Sharkbelly: If you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` you will get a list of packages and their versions printed near the end of the `.log` file. You can compare the log at your local machine with that of ShareLaTeX.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. To make sure that the problem is really about `pgfplots`, before further investigations in that direction. Of course if someone knows it's a `pgfplot`-related issue, that will make my comment obsolete.

Comment: @anderstood You're right that it could be something else, but it seems most likely to be a `pgfplots`(/`tikz`) issue, considering that manifests as a mistranslation of coordinates when using `tikz` macros in an `axis` environment. Not sure how that could show up in a document containing only text.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In fact I focused on the change of font, before caring about the misplaced nodes. What I had in mind is that the observation could be due to an elementary mistake (like compiling with another header). I can't see why the fonts wouldn't be the same otherwise.

Comment: @anderstood Ah, I didn't even notice that, the question didn't say anything about it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, your suggestion of using \listfiles (which was new to me) revealed some discrepancies, so I have updated my packages, and the issue has been resolved.  Unfortunately, I couldn't tell you exactly which package was to blame, but I am so glad to know about this trick.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. I guess we'll close this question then, that's what we usually do with things like this, where an update solved things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by updating packages.